# Office 365: Management API Resource disabled

Tags: office365, office365api

I'm trying to access the Management activity [API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt227394.aspx) for tenant level (Azure AD, Sharepoint, Exchange) events but when I make an API call I get this in response

```
{
  "error": "invalid_resource",
  "error_description": "AADSTS50001: Resource 'https://manage.office.com' is disabled.\r\nTrace ID: 000000f-0000-41fe-8c0d-ec36ca569dff\r\nCorrelation ID: 00000000-e219-4ff7-0000-17e8ce04332d\r\nTimestamp: 2016-07-26 02:21:08Z",
  "error_codes": [50001],
  "timestamp": "2016-07-26 02:21:08Z",
  "trace_id": "11122121-438d-41fe-Gcpd-ec36ca569ccc",
  "correlation_id": "nxnxnxzz-e253-4ff7-8753-17e8ce04332d"
}
```

Where do I enable this resource in my tenant settings? It works fine for other tenants.

Comment: Is the tenant is a Office 365 tenant?

Comment: @FeiXue Yes it is.